# How to kill /re-start a long running task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Is there a way to kill / re-start a long running task in AWS SWF? Sometimes some of our tasks run for a longer duration and we would like to manually kill a certain task (either via UI or programmatically) and re-start the task if possible. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Console is option to manually kill workflow.

You can also set timeouts to whole workflow execution time or to individual activities. This can be set when you register your activity or when you start your activity (defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSecond).

It's not clear what language you're using.

If you're using java, then you should look into [Exponential Retry](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/interceptors.html) in Flow Framework. This make SDK restart your activity if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Long running activity is expected to heartbeat using [RecordActivityTaskHeartbeat](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RecordActivityTaskHeartbeat.html). It leads to timeout failure after short hearbeat interval instead of long task execution timeout if the activity process hangs or crashes.

The workflow code (decider) can always request activity cancellation through [RequestCancelActivityTask](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RequestCancelActivityTaskDecisionAttributes.html) decision. The cancellation request is returned as output of the [RecordActivityTaskHeartbeat](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RecordActivityTaskHeartbeat.html) call. Activity implementation should cancel itself and report back to the service using [RespondActivityTaskCanceled](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_RespondActivityTaskCanceled.html) API call.

See [Error Handling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/errorhandling.htm) section of [AWS Flow Framework Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/) for the AWS Flow Framework way of cancelling activities.

Sometimes activity implementation cannot support heartbeating and self cancellation. The solution is to execute another *kill* activity that terminates the first activity execution. For example under Unix such kill activity could emit "kill -9" command for the process that implements the first one.